# Can't clean known_hosts in macOS 10.13

Tags: macos, ssh

I have reinstalled the OS of my remote server, and now when I try to `ssh root@myserverIP` from my local machine I get:

```
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@    WARNING: REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED!     @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
IT IS POSSIBLE THAT SOMEONE IS DOING SOMETHING NASTY!
Someone could be eavesdropping on you right now (man-in-the-middle attack)!
It is also possible that a host key has just been changed.
The fingerprint for the ECDSA key sent by the remote host is
SHA256:xxxxxxxxxxx.
Please contact your system administrator.
Add correct host key in /var/root/.ssh/known_hosts to get rid of this message.
Offending ECDSA key in /var/root/.ssh/known_hosts:3
ECDSA host key for xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx has changed and you have requested strict checking.
Host key verification failed.
```

(`xxx` is just to hide the real info)

Instead of changing the key, I have opted for full deletion of all the content in `.ssh/known_hosts`, hoping to be prompted to add the key again. But instead, I still get the very same error.

So, I have even tried to remove the the single key manually:

```
ssh-keygen -R xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

And, of course, it is not there since `known_hosts` is now empty:

```
Host xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx not found in /Users/xxx/.ssh/known_hosts
```

However, I am still getting the same error over and over. This is puzzling- where does `ssh` get the info from if `known_hosts` is blank?

Of course, I have restarted my Mac, and I have even flushed the cache. Maybe `ssh` is using another `known_hosts`? But where is it? I tried to `locate` it but I can't find any other `known_hosts` file in my drive.

What am I doing wrong? How can I solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## You have more than one `known_hosts` file

It seems from your description you removed the key from *your* `known_hosts` file:

> ```
> Host xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx not found in /Users/xxx/.ssh/known_hosts
> ```

Where `/Users/xxx/` is presumably your home directory. However, the original error message complains:

> ```
> Offending ECDSA key in /var/root/.ssh/known_hosts:3
> ```

So, remove the key from `/var/root/.ssh/known_hosts` and the error message will disappear.

Comment: Why `ssh-keygen -R xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx` would not work then? I am not supposed to have access to `/var/root/.ssh/known_hosts`

Comment: However, I have changed the permission and modified that file and now it is working. Thanks. Still puzzled about `ssh-keygen -R xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx` and by the fact that `locate` did not output `/var/root/.ssh/known_hosts`

Comment: @alec_djinn Fair points! The `locate` question and how `ssh-keygen -R` works on macos might make for interesting follow-up questions. I don't know off the top of my head why they work (or didn't work!) in the way they do- but I'd certainly be interested to find out :)

Comment: (I could make educated guesses for both, but definitive answers are always welcome!)

Comment: @alec_djinn `ssh-keygen -R` only operates on the current user's known_hosts file (unless you specify a different one with `-f`). I assume you're running `ssh` as root (and that's why it's using /var/root/.ssh/known_hosts instead of your file)? No user other than root has access to the /var/root/.ssh directory.